# Precedence in syntax analyst

Tags: syntax, antlr4

```
<exp> → <term> ASSIGN <exp> | <term> 
<term> → <term> EXPONENT <fact> | <term> ADDOP <fact> | <fact> 
<fact> → <opeand> RELOP <operand> | <operand> 
<operand> → LB <exp> RB | ID
```

So in this case,which one has the highest,lowest precedence and which one  has equal precedence to another operator ? ( ASSIGN,EXPONENT,ADDOP,RELOP )

Answer (score 0):

Antlr rules do not define operator precedence in the sense that its rule matching simply follows from the literal sequence of the supplied input text.

Rather, operator precedence is typically defined in user-supplied logic applied in the analysis of the generated parse-tree.  That is, given a parse-tree node representing a parser rule that, for example, matches the form

```
x = a * b + c
```

the existence of the node signifies only that the necessary sequence of symbols has been matched.  The logic implemented in the parse-tree visitor that visits that node is then free to define any desired relative operator precedence.